# TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to do **Feature Scaling** in a dataset, but I get an error and have no idea how to proceed:

```
    > Traceback (most recent call last):
    > 
    >   File "<ipython-input-10-71bea414b4d0>", line 22, in <module>
    >     x_train = sc_X.fit_transform(x_train)
    > 
    > TypeError: fit_transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'X'
```

and here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values
# Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values="NaN", strategy="mean", axis=0)
imputer = Imputer.fit(imputer,X[:,1:3])
X[:, 1:3] = Imputer.transform(imputer,X[:, 1:3])

#Spliting the dataset into Training set and Test Set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size= 0.2, random_state= 0)

#Feature Scalling

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler
x_train = sc_X.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test = sc_X.transform(x_test)
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You are assigning `sc_X` a reference to the `StandardScaler` class.
but `fit_transform()` is is not a class method, but an instance method.
This means that you have to create an instance of the class.

So,

```
sc_X = StandardScaler
```

should be:

```
sc_X = StandardScaler()
```

Comment: This answer could use some more explanation about why the first line above is wrong.   StandardScaler is a class, so why can't we just pass just its name? I may be mistaken, but, I think the issue is the difference between the name of a class and a new instance of it, but don't you think this answer could benefit from at least one more sentence of explanation to that effect?

Answer (score 0):

`imputer` is a method and `Imputer` is a class

So, change the code as below, and other such occurrences in this code:

```
imputer = imputer.fit(imputer,X[:,1:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the class instance :

```
sc_X = StandardScaler()
```

as `fit_transform()` is instance method not a class method

Answer (score 0):

just keep brackets for StandardScaler function
Ans:-
StandardScaler()